# Full Text Justification in SSRS 2008R2

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Is there any way to full justify text in SSRS 2008R2. I guess there is no direct option for it. Please suggest any work around to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a well known limitation of SSRS. Take a look at connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/404966/full-justification-in-reporting-services-2008-needed
They suggests a [workaround](http://www.fyireporting.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=552) that may fit your needs (you'll need access to your reportserver)